# firebase functions deploy got an error with file path that contains "\"

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When I tried to deploy firebase functions, the process of loading credential file occurs an error:

> Detailed stack trace: Error: Failed to read credentials from file C:\Users\kracc\Desktop\code\glint-server\firebase-account.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kracc\Desktop\code\glint-server\firebase-account.json'

Initialization code:

```js
private connectFireStore(): void {
  initializeApp({
    credential: applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIRESTORE_URL,
  })
}
```

folder structure:

[image]

and value of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in `.env.prod` is `../../firebase-account.json`

I can open `C:\Users\kracc\Desktop\code\glint-server\firebase-account.json` and it works well when I use emulator and local server

reason why I think the backslash matters is I saw it couldn't understand backslash included path in `require` function (`require('./lib\\foo')` got an error).

how can I deal with this situation?

Comment: Are you sure you have `firebase-account.json` in the `gslint-server` directory? Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: for sure. I opened run(window + r) and pasted the path then the file opens well. Is backslash a real problem?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are trying to load the credentials? Also the screenshot of your directory strcuture? r

Comment: @Dharmaraj I updated my question. Please have a look :)

Comment: Don't check path relative to the compiled code. In your `server.ts`, you can just try `initializeApp({ credential: "./firebase-account.json" })`